# Конструкция do.call(function(...) Map(list, ...), cars) в языке R - порядок обхода аргументов

Tags: r

Не будут ли уважаемые коллеги настолько любезны, чтоб пояснять, каков принцип обхода аргументов в конструкции   do.call(function(...) Map(list, ...), cars)  ?
Почему в отличии от прямой конструкции Map(list, cars) результат будет отличаться порядком (грубо говоря произойдет "транспонирование" матрицы).  (Речь о языке - ["R"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language))).

```
cars <- list(list("white BMW", "black BMW","1_3"), list("white GMC", "black GMC","2_3"), list("3 white GMC", "3 black GMC","3 2_3") )

do.call(function(...) Map(list, ...), cars)
```

Выдаст ответ:

> 'white BMW' 'white GMC' '3 white GMC'
>
> 'black BMW' 'black GMC' '3 black GMC'
>
> '1_3' '2_3' '3 2_3'

В отличии от Map(list, cars)

> 'white BMW' 'black BMW' '1_3'
>
> 'white GMC' 'black GMC' '2_3'
>
> '3 white GMC' '3 black GMC' '3 2_3'

Пример ноутбука с кодами :

https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/r-do-call-map-with-3-dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри `do.call()` происходит вычисление выражения `Map(list, list("white BMW", "black BMW","1_3"), list("white GMC", "black GMC","2_3"), list("3 white GMC", "3 black GMC","3 2_3"))`.

Дело в том, что

```
args    a list of arguments to the function call. The names attribute of args gives the argument names.
```

И вместо `...` подставляется не один объект `cars` (список списков), а все вложенные списки по отдельности.

Comment: Cпасибо большое ! Кажется понятно. А можно источник цитаты , пожалуйста ?

Comment: Ответ найден : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call  Но простому человеку не тривиально понять, что это надо прочесть как "И вместо ... подставляется не один объект cars (список списков), а все вложенные списки по отдельности. "